# What is the maximum flickr API limit available and how do you go about getting it?

Tags: yahoo, flickr

According to the Flickr [API documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/):

```
If your application stays under 3600 queries per hour ... you'll be fine.
```

According to Yahoo [Developer documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/flickr/):

```
Access through YQL is limited to 10,000 signed calls per hour
```

I am currently using Flickr's direct API and I am unfamiliar with YQL. Is it necessary for me to rewrite using YQL to obtain the 10,000 call limit or is there a way to increase my limit while using the direct flickr API?

Why do the two APIs to the same service have different limits?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/What-is-the-maximum-flickr-API/1361494903655-6a1e3a51-cd41-411e-86a9-dc2dee898ab5) the lower limit applies. They also state that commercial licenses with higher limits are available.